# Ask Different Name

Tags: discussion

Why is the Apple SE called Ask Different? I don't know why because Apple may not actually be on there to help, but Different doesn't have anything to do with it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different

Comment: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/286

Comment: i find this question pretty useful. It's the first thing I wondered when I read an answer on Apple StackExchange. Maybe the closing of "off-topic" questions should be more helpful by suggesting where it may be on-topic instead of just closing things down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a play on Apple's tagline/slogan [*Think Different*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different) from 1997-2002.